# Как обратиться к getSimOperatorName() в Android через плагин для Unity?

Tags: android, unity3d, плагин

Пытаюсь написать плагин для Unity, чтобы получить доступ к методам `getSimOperatorName()` и `getNetworkOperatorName()` на Android. В Android Studio создал AAR библиотеку из двух классов. Нужна помощь.

```
package com.eppz.myplugin;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
public class My_Plugin extends Activity
{
    static Context context = MyApplication.getContext();
    static String test = "";

    public static String getMessage()
    {
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = ((TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));

        try {
            test = telephonyManager.getSimOperatorName();
        }catch (Exception e){
            test = e.getMessage();
        }
        return test;}
}
```

2 класса

```
package com.eppz.myplugin;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }
```

Error Log

> 05-08 05:23:26.245 30107-30152/? I/Unity: AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.Object
>   android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.Object
>   android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                     at com.eppz.myplugin.My_Plugin.getMessage(My_Plugin.java:15)
>                                                     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
>                                                     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
>                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                   at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CheckException () [0x00000] in :0 
>                                                   at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CallStaticStringMethod (IntPtr clazz,
>   IntPtr methodID, UnityEngine.jvalue[] args) [0x00000] in :0 
>                                                   at UnityEngine.Androi

Comment: 1. Убедитесь что Application инициализируется статическим конструктором (в чём я сомневаюсь), либо перепишите ваш "static Context context = MyApplication.getContext();" на инициализацию синглетоном. 2. судя по исключению, ваш Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE, либо ваш telephonyManager  после всех инициализаций, таки, равен nullptr.